# what is loss of resolution in homogenous coordinate system?

Tags: math, graphics, computational-geometry, homogenous-transformation

From what I understood from the image below is that the homogenous coordinates is a way around the range limit of an n-bit computer. However there's still some confusion since reading about it online, the explanation is quite complicated for me to understand. Then there is also the main question of what is a resolution loss as mentioned in very last paragraph of the image.

This stuff is a confusing me. Can anyone point me in the right direction so as to get the clear idea about these basics?

A paragraph from Mathematical Elements for Computer Graphics - David F. Rogers, J. Alan Adams
[image]
[]

Comment: Please read [W-buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/w-buffering) and [Depth buffer FAQ](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm#0070) and [Depth Buffer - The gritty details](https://web.archive.org/web/20081015234602/http://www.codermind.com/articles/Depth-buffer-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homogeneous integer coordinates are basically floating point coordinates, except that the exponent part is shared by all the dimensions.

The "resolution loss" referred to is the fact that when the exponent (h) is 2, for example, then all of the coordinates are multiplied by 2, so you can't represent odd numbers.

This is a reasonable thing to do under the constraints of the time, since it saves space and provides the same accuracy in all dimensions.

As Yves indicates, nobody does this anymore, since hardware support for floating point is widespread.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is outdated (except for the happy few how are still able to deal with integer coordinates). Nowadays you work with floating-point numbers and don't worry about resolution.

Anyway " homogenous coordinates is a way around the range limit of an n-bit computer" was not the idea.